# Method call from one class to another not working?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble getting the below code to work. I am calling a method from another class and I am getting back an error that the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
public class QCMeClass
{
  public string FindDataLocation(string itemId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId)) { return itemId; }
        ...
        return "";
    }
}

public class PimsController
{ 
  public void ScanLoadedItems(string username, string password, string sid)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = OracleConnect(username, password, sid);
        string item = "Test";
        QCMeClass qcmeObj= new QCMeClass();

        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(qcmeObj.FindDataLocation(item)))
            {
                  ...
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? This is very important information and should never be left out.

Comment: Also, `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is worse than nothing, since the only thing it does is reset the stack-trace, hiding the source of the error. Remove the entire `catch` block (and its `try`), run the code again, and see which line threw the error.

Comment: I appologize, I thought it was obvious which line would throw the exception. The line  {if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(qcmeObj.FindDataLocation(item)))} is throwing the excpetion. Not sure why because I have declared a new instance of this object in QCMeClass qcmeObj= new QCMeClass();

Comment: @Blorgbeard I only added throw ex; just for the sake of showing example here, I usually handle exceptions differently.

Comment: fair enough. BTW, do you know that you can also just `throw`? It doesn't reset the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I jumped the pistol a bit too quick here and missed something in QCMeClass. QCMeClass calls a third method in another class. I needed to add and assign an object for method3.

So in QCMeClass I declared

```
public MainForm formObj;
```

And then in the calling method PimsController() I added.

```
QCMeClass instance = new QCMeClass();
instance.formObj= this.formObj;
```

Comment: To circumvent this situations i recommend to always set all class members to a valid default value (from inside the class) when using the default constructor for instantiation. This way you can avoid unexpected behaviour.